# How to resolve name conflict between class name and function name

Tags: c++

Is there any (good) way of having equally named class and global function in the same namespace in C++?

Below code does not compile because it favors function over class name.

```
void PrintNumber( int val ) 
{ 
  std::cout << "from function: " << val << std::endl;
}
struct PrintNumber {
  void operator()( int val ) const 
  { 
    std::cout << "from operator: " << val << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  auto f1 = std::function<void(int)>( PrintNumber() ) ; // Functor class instance // ERROR occurs here
  auto f2 = std::function<void(int)>( PrintNumber ) ;   // Global function
  f1( 123 );
  f2( 456 );
  cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but the obvious solution would be to rename the class to `NumberPrinter` or similar. `PrintNumber` isn't a good class name.

Comment: Rename class/structure like CNumberPrinter to StructNumberPrinter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the full name `struct PrintNumber`. This can't be done directly in your initialization of `std::function`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

struct PrintNumber {
  void operator()( int val ) const
  {
    std::cout << "from operator: " << val << std::endl;
  }
};
void PrintNumber( int val )
{
  std::cout << "from function: " << val << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  struct PrintNumber p;
  auto f1 = std::function<void(int)>( p ) ; // Functor class instance occurs here
  auto f2 = std::function<void(int)>( PrintNumber ) ;   // Global function
  f1( 123 );
  f2( 456 );
  std::cin.get();
}
```

though probably best to change names or namespaces to avoid ambiguity.